# Accessing externally connected camera in ios application developed using phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova, camera

I am working on an application in phonegap and will need to access and allow users to take photos with an externally connected camera.

I was wondering if anyone has experience with this or knows if it is possible via a phonegap plugin or within phonegap API directly.

Comment: i guess u'll have to write a plugin

Comment: Hey, I want same thing. Do you get any solution for this?